# Two showers with two different water temperatures

Tags: shower

I have 2 showers upstairs in my colonial, one in each bedroom. However the hot water temperature coming out of one is significantly lower than that of the other. I had the cartridge replaced on the one with lower temperature.

Is there anything I can do to equalize the temperatures?

Comment: For anyone to be able to answer this you need to tell us what valves are there.  We can’t even see the shape of the knobs from here.  Also have you measured actual temp from each?  How different are they?  Does your home have 1 hot water heater or multiple?  How old are the valves?new enough that they have anti-scald?  Also had it always been this way, or is this a new issue?

Comment: are the showers adjacent? one might just have longer pipes through colder cross sections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cartridge comes from the factory with a temperature mix set point. You can adjust the set point on the cartridge - the manufacturers directions should show you how to do this - and since you replaced the cartridge yourself - it should be easy for you to do, and you can then check and adjust your other shower as well if you like.

I will say this - there is no indicator that says 110 Degrees turn to this point here. You will need to do a bit of trial and error ..